# iframe height but not width

Tags: css, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-iframe, autogrow

In my facebook page I added my iframe app
with setting : Canvas Width Fixed (760px)
and Height Fixed 800px;

I call FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow(90); and it work fine for height but not for width.
is it normal? I want to my iframe width take about 740px.
https://www.facebook.com/pages/Camping-Demonstration/167138953341219?sk=app_191265277583854

I tried with setSize and it work just for the height too. what did I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a page tab app and the settings you just mentioned are for canvas apps - the settings for page tabs are on the main page of app settings, in the same section you enter the Page Tab URL and Secure Page Tab URL values

Comment: oh my god, you're right thanks a lot, I'was working on this issue while 5hours